# The way to select the Postgres database in JetBrains' DataGrip

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I'm new to PostgreSQL, how can I select an existing database? I have successfully created a new database with this SQL command:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb
```

But there is no such syntax as `USE dbname` like in MySql. I've already looked for solution on internet and I've found that the query for this purposes is `\connect dbname`.

But DataGrip tells 'Nothing to run' when I'm trying to execute that. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to select psql DB in DataGrip?

Comment: You can only specify the database when you connect to it. You can not switch the database without creating a new connection.